# Internationalization CakePHP 1.3 not updating

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, poedit

A long time ago I was developing this project and now I'm back on it. The internationalization was working fine, getting the translations from the folder `C:\...\cake\app\locale\por\LC_MESSAGES` where I have 2 files:

```
default.mo
default.po
```

I edited the po file, inserted manually some new keywords, for instance:

```
msgid "id"
msgstr "Código"
```

Then, I opened the Poedit, validate everything, and than clicked "save", so Poedit create the .mo file automatically.

After that I restarted WAMP, and cleared my cache.

I did all that a lot of times, but the result is allways the same: the old words are being translated fine, but the new words I added recently, do not translate.

The old ones and the new ones, I'm use in my CakePHP 1.3 project in this way:

```
<?php __('id'); ?>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried using Poedit and updating the .po with the menu item "Update from pot-file"?

Answer (score 3):

Use alternative editors. i recommend using https://poeditor.com/
It's online solution, easy to use. also has import and exprt options.

Answer (score 0):

The .mo file is a compiled translation which may get cached by the `gettext` engine.

You should disable generation of .mo files (at least during development) so changes in translations are always picked up.